# Animate all SnakeAnimations at once instead of one - Leaflet js

Tags: javascript, google-maps, leaflet

Currently I am using Leaflet JS and an addon called "SnakeAnim" which can be found
[here](https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim)
All of my map markers before using the snake animation were loading together and drawing an arc from the markers starting position to a certain location all at once. 
All of the markers end at this certain location for their arc.

My problem is when I use the SnakeIn() function that it only animates one marker at a time, what I want it to do is animate them all together, simultaneously.

Inside my PopulateMap function I have:

```
                    lg.addLayer(L.marker(latlng, { icon: cssIcon }));
                    lg.addLayer(L.Polyline.Arc([latlng.lat, latlng.lng],
                    [netLat, netLong],
                    {
                        color: "red",
                        vertices: 50,
                        weight: 1,
                        opacity: 1,
                        snakeSpeed: 50
                    }));
                    return lg;
```

**Note!** **netLat + netLong always have the same values.**

Once returned I add it to the map and call the snakeIn() function.

```
    .addTo(map).snakeIn();
```

Using this code it produces one marker, draws an arc from the marker start location to the end location, then loads the next marker and repeats the process.

I tried doing this also and removed the .snakeIn() part from the end of .addTo(map):

```
                    lg.addLayer(L.marker(latlng, { icon: cssIcon }));
                    lg.addLayer(L.Polyline.Arc([latlng.lat, latlng.lng],
                    [netLat, netLong],
                    {
                        color: "red",
                        vertices: 50,
                        weight: 1,
                        opacity: 1,
                        snakeSpeed: 0
                    }).snakeIn());
```

This way did, in-fact load all of the markers at once, but also it loaded the arcs with no animation except for 1. The very last marker was the only one that would animate not the others.

So I'm wondering if anybody else has experienced this same problem and worked around it or if anybody has any ideas on how I would accomplish this.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Please can you show some screenshot of your markers and arc without animation, then what you would like to achieve? Ideally reproduce your issue in Plunker / JSBin / JSFiddle, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody with a similar problem, mine was related to adding them to lg.addLayer method.

What I do now is I add them to the map rather than the lg.layer:

```
        function drawArc(source, destination, leafletMap) {
        for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
        L.Polyline.Arc([source[i].geometry.coordinates[1], source[i].geometry.coordinates[0]],
                destination,
                {
                    color: "red",
                    vertices: 200,
                    snakingSpeed: 200
                })
            .addTo(leafletMap).snakeIn();
    }
}
```

This way, all of my lines start animating at the same time.